# parsing the csv file to import to android app

Tags: java, android, csv, opencsv

i am working with android app to import the csv file to populate my DB.

I am using OpenCSV library to do it. I wish to use CSV reader to read from the inputstream.

I am using import feature from the gmail, so i use `android:scheme=content` 
it makes csv file come as `InputStream`.

Inside I have 3 columns. Some rows have `,` character.

So when I try to separate columns using `,` I get error.

I wish help to know how to overcome this issue of comma inside the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get your csv with another separator character? if yes, the you can call yor csv reader with this separator, from de docs...

```
    CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator)
       Constructs CSVReader with supplied separator.
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is comma in columns, it gets difficult to read a csv file properly, I will show you the code that doesn't requires any library:

```
   File f=new File("C:/Users/Public/"+filename+".csv");             

            Scanner sc=new Scanner(fc);
            sc.useDelimiter("\r");
            char cd='"';

            //Create scanner string seperator ","

            String g=String.valueOf(cd)+","+String.valueOf(cd);

            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "G: "+g);

            String[] data=null;

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){

                data=null;

                csvtemp=sc.nextLine().toString();
            //remove first character ", string from second character                    
                csvtemp=csvtemp.subString(1);
                //remove last character ", string from first character to secondlast
                csvtemp=csvtemp.subString(0,csvtemp.length()-1);
                //Split record by seperator ","  and copy to array
                data=csvtemp.split(g);
            }   


            sc.close();
```